# Ruby environment messed up, How to uninstall ruby-gems-rails from Leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my ruby environment in my mac Leopard is all messed up. And I want to uninstall the entire ruby, gem stack and install them again from scratch. How can I do it ?please point me towards a good resource on the net.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't Uninstall the pre-installed Ruby in Mac](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/235258)

And have you tried [rubyosx](http://rubyosx.rubyforge.org/)?

Comment: The ruby in /usr/local/bin can be removed using this: http://punctuatedproductivity.com/2007/11/01/uninstalling-ruby-installed-by-source-on-os-x/#benefit

Comment: im trying with this http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com). Makes running multiple rubies and gemsets a breeze.

Comment: +1 for RVM. I'd also suggest pairing that with [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/), which is a great way to install other libraries without messing around with OSX defaults.

Comment: I "third" the recommendation for rvm. It sets up your Ruby environment as a .rvm directory in your home directory. rvm then makes it easy to uninstall a particular Ruby instance, or all of them, and easily reinstall. Also, Wayne is easily reached on the IRC channel and often has the answer for your questions within seconds. Highly recommended.